# How to put my incoming data into a sortedlist?

Tags: c#, loops, timer, serial-port, sortedlist

I wrote a C# code that will send functions ( 1-9) to a micro controller and the controller will send back data to my computer via RS232(SERIAL PORT). The problem that I am having is im trying to get the incoming data and put it in a sortedlist. The sorted list key will be date/time and the values will be the incoming data. I attempted to add the sortedlist portion to my code but it was unsuccessful. The errors i am getting are :

Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'int' to 'serialreadwrite.SMCValues'

CS0162  Unreachable code detected   SMCData-

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Timers;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace serialreadwrite
{

public class SMCValues
{
    public string ArrayVoltage;
    public string ArrayCurrent;
    public string AutoMPPT;
    public string MotorVoltage;
    public string ArrayAmps;
    public string MaxMotorVoltage;
    public string MotorRPM;
    public string SerialNumber;
    public string SMCType;






    class Program

    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 1000;
            _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 1000;
            _serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
            _serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            _serialPort.Open();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                string c = Convert.ToString(i);
                byte[] array_out = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(c); //convert i to the right variable type;
                _serialPort.Write(array_out, 0, array_out.Length);
                byte[] array_out2 = new byte[1];
                array_out2[0] = 0xD;
                _serialPort.Write(array_out2, 0, array_out2.Length);

                //print what you receive 
                int k = 0;
                int reader = 0;
                string fullstring = "";
                while (k < 23)
                {
                    reader = _serialPort.ReadByte();
                    fullstring += Convert.ToChar(reader);
                    k++;


                    DateTime cur = DateTime.Now;
                    SortedList<DateTime, SMCValues> mySL1 = new SortedList<DateTime, SMCValues>();
                    Console.WriteLine(" (mySL1):");
                    while (true)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                        {
                            string p = Convert.ToString(j);
                            cur = DateTime.Now;
                            mySL1.Add(cur, j); // j is throwing the errror
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

                        }
                        foreach (KeyValuePair<DateTime, SMCValues> kvp in mySL1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("my first key is = {0}, and my first value is = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                        }
                        Thread.Sleep(5000);



                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(fullstring);
                    _serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
                    _serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();


                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: can not convert from int to what?

Comment: Sorry about that, to 'serialreadwrite.SMCValues' @Jacobr365

Comment: What line throws the errors? Can you edit the question and show the stacktrace for the errors. including the line that throws it.

Comment: i added a comment next to the line that causes the error @Jacobr365

Comment: what member of smcValues is storing j? It looks like you want a sorted list of SMCValues objects. is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the SMCVales are objects that I would like to be declared as the information being received @Jacobr365

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign an integer value 'j', to a 'SMCValues' which is a class.

It seems from your question that you are initially trying to verify that you can get a sorted list of dates to work, so you can temporarily make the following change:

`//SortedList<DateTime, SMCValues> mySL1 = new SortedList<DateTime, SMCValues>();
SortedList<DateTime, int> mySL1 = new SortedList<DateTime, int>();`

You will need to change your foreach as well.

Then later when you are ready, swap back to the original declaration and make sure you are using 'SMCValues' in your .Add statement